# SonarQube & JaCoCo (mvn) naming convention

Tags: java, testing, junit, sonarqube, jacoco

I started using SonnaQube & JaCoCO (java mvn) and I noticed that some test when I name them like this ("myClassTest")doesn't count in the coverage statistic but when I name it like this ("myClassIT") it counts.

What I figured out is that every time you need the Applications context you have to use "IT".

I was wondering if there is a written down documentation on how to name what test exactly.

When I lock up the Integrations test it doesn't seem to be the same Definition because in my test I just use mocked APIs and doesn't test against other running Applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the Maven Surefile Plugin test naming conventions for unit tests:
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

For Integration tests I believe it is just classes ending with `IT`. Not sure where to find a documentation for those to be honest.

Comment: Integration tests typically executed by maven-failsafe-plugin, so similar documentation is at http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html